# the question about the proof of analyticity of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

On the clip , https://youtu.be/E7NNc-AM7vQ?t=385 (at the current time), the speaker checkes that $P_n(z)$ = $\int_{n}^{n+1} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$  is analytic function. To do so, he referred

> "Use Thm5 (on the screen) : $\int H(\omega, z) d\omega $" (In case of 
>   $P_n(z)$, using variable t instead of $\omega$ )

The question is  what is Thm5?... (Although I have tried to google, I cannot find the theorem which is analgolous to the Thm5 on the screen....)

Comment: $\int_{n}^{n+1}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt=\int_{\log n}^{\log (n+1)}e^{uz}e^{-e^u}du$ is analytic by direct expansion of $e^{uz}$ in power series and use absolute convergence to exchange $\sum,\int$. For $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t}dt,\Re(z) > 0$ you can use that it is $= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{u(z-a)} e^{au} e^{-e^u}du$ and expand $e^{(z-a)t}$ in power series in $z-a$, the obtained power series will converge for $|z-a|< |\Re(a)|$. The theorem is to avoid those computations and show that the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of analytic functions is analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove analyticity is to use Morera's Theorem.

Let $g(z)=\int_a^{b} H(t,z)dt$ where $H$ is continuous in the first variable and analytic in the second variable. We can show that $H$ is jointly measurable. Also $g$ is continuous by DCT. Consider any open ball $B(z,r)$ in the domain and let $\gamma$ be a closed path in it. Then $\int_{\gamma} g(z)dz=\int_a^{b} \int_{\gamma} H(t,z)dzdt$ by Fubini's Theorem and $\int_{\gamma} H(t,z)dz=0$ for each $t$. Hence $\int_{\gamma} g(z)dz=0$ for every closed path $\gamma$ which implies that $g$ is analytic in $B(z,r)$.